# Unable to install or remove Java 8u111

Tags: java

My `Add or Remove Programs` from Control Panel does not show presence of a java program. But the directory is there, with all files intact, it seems, at c:\program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_111. When attempting to re-install from java.com I get a message "Directory is not empty". But it does not say that I already have the most recent version.

I had an indication that Google Chrome was not functioning right (on attempting to open interactive pages I would get an error message "Plugin not loaded". I reinstalled Chrome and that problem is gone). Also some files in OneNote look odd  (with handwriting overlapping itself). But otherwise I do not notice any issue with my laptop. So I am not sure if this is a virus or a bad Java download.

Any suggestions?

[There is a Microsoft utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) for removing unseen programs but it requires a "product code" . A 28 (or 32)-letter string I believe. What is the product code for 8u101 and 8u111?

Comment: Is there a Microsoft Utility to remove the program: No; But a third-party program does exist for Java: https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/ its not supported because Oracle resolved the problem it was meant to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Java link (https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml) and you will see where you need to disable Java for Browser.  I did that and was able to install Java 8u111 after doing so.  I then re-enabled Java for Browser.  Hope this helps you.